# Why does this Lemma applies?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hulek, *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*, page 54, I'm stuck on an argument the author uses to prove that certain subset is open.

Specifically, application of Lemma 1.42: [image]

Some of the concepts used in those lines that could help: here $V\subset \mathbb{A}_{k}^n$ and $W\subset \mathbb{A}_k^m$ are irreducible algebraic sets.

- Lemma 1.42 simply states that a polynomial map $f\colon V\to W$ is Zariski continuous.
- A rational map $f\colon V\dashrightarrow W$ is an $m$-tuple $f=(f_1,\ldots, f_m)$ with $f_i\in k(V)$, the field of fractions of the coordinate ring $k[V]$ of $V$, such that $f(p)\in W$ for all $p\in \operatorname{dom}(f)$.
- $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is the set of points $p\in V$ at which every $f_i$ is regular, and $f_i$ is regular at $p$ if there is some representation $f_i=g_i/h_i$ with $g_i,h_i\in k[V]$ and $h(p)\neq 0$.
- $f\colon V\dashrightarrow W$ is dominant if $f(\operatorname{dom}(f))$ is a Zariski dense subset of $W$.
- For $U\subset W$ the inverse image of $U$ under the rational map $f$ is defined to be $f^{-1}(U)=\{p\in \operatorname{dom}(f)\colon f(p)\in U\}$

I was trying to see that maybe every component function of $f$ defines a *polynomial map* over $V$ (or over certain open/closed subset of $V$?) and then trying to see $f^{-1}(\operatorname{dom}(g))$ as union of open subsets, and is in here where Lemma 1.42 applies: these open subsets are preimages of $\operatorname{dom}(g)$ under certain compositions of polynomial maps involving the $f_i$'s. But I'm not able to claim that.

If there are some missing concepts, feel free to ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Continuity means the inverse image of an open is open. It’s dense because it’s open in an irreducible space

Comment: @leibnewtz yes but why is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Well $f$ is a rational map. This means it’s a regular map on its domain and hence continuous where it’s defined

Comment: @leibnewtz can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Consider the simplest example of a rational function $f/g$ on $\mathbb{A}^1$. This is defined on the complement of the zero set of $g$. Now ask yourself what elements of the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{g=0\}$ look like.

Comment: @leibnewtz sorry but the author defines the coordinate ring only for algebraic sets so I'm not following you

Comment: The space $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{g=0 \}$ can be given the structure of an algebraic set. Namely, it's the vanishing locus in $\mathbb{A}^2$ of the function $yg-1$